# where to look for?

Tags: android

I am new to android and I am having trouble searching for the valid data to put in my code.

especially the building manifest file is giving me a headache.

```
<action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED/>
```

Now where to find what other is valid in place of "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"??

Is "android.provider.Telephony.DATA_SMS_RECEIVED" valid????

This might be a silly question but I really don't know where to search for this stuff..

I would be really thankful if someone can answer to me

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These should help...

[The AndroidManifest.xml File](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html)

[Manifest.Permission](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html)

Comment: i searched your link for Manifest.Permission. Thanks now I can search for all the valid permission available for Manifest. Can you provide me the link for all valid action??? Thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Now I know where to look for the standard action as well. Anyone else looking for the same answer can find it here.    http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html